How to deal with FFmpeg crashing because file is too big?
I accidentally rendered a long video in blender backwards. The actors are moving in reverse. The sound is normal. The easy way to fix this is:
ffmpeg -i originalVideo.mp4 -vf reverse reversedVideo.mp4

But that uses up all the memory in my Manjaro (Linux) computer and crashes FFmpeg.
So how can I do this? I am open to using other software but this way seemed best.
It takes 12 hours to render so re-rendering is to much time.

Do keep in mind: Whatever you try, you must re-encode the entirety of the video. This will take time and it will reduce quality. If rendering the video in Blender takes a mere 12 hours, it might still be the best choice here.

Thanks, I guess I must accept the price of my error! :-(

Using segments.
For example, this is 20 minute segments:
ffmpeg -i originalVideo.mp4 -an -f segment -segment_time 1200 -c copy %02d_originalVideo_segment.mp4

The -an and -vn are no audio/video flags. To keep original audio, use this, adjusting the .aac to whatever format the file contains:
ffmpeg -i originalVideo.mp4 -vn -c copy audio.aac

If you are unsure, you can find out the type with: ffprobe originalVideo.mp4.
Convert each segment with -vf reverse to avoid running out of memory.
Then, concatenate the video:
list.txt
file '/path/to/01_originalVideo_segment.mp4'
file '/path/to/02_originalVideo_segment.mp4'
file '/path/to/03_originalVideo_segment.mp4'

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy final_video.mp4

Merge the video back with the audio:
ffmpeg -i final_video.mp4 -i audio.aac -c copy final_mux.mp4

